# When I type 'echo $path' in Terminal, I see only a blank line - why?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, path

I know I have a $path variable. If I type 'env' or 'set' at the Terminal command line, I can see what's in the $path variable - along with lots of other extraneous stuff. But if I just type 'echo $path', I see only a blank line. What is wrong? I'm El Capitan (10.11.6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment variable name are case sensitive. Try typing `echo $PATH` instead.